# Error when deleting a file in use with python

Tags: python, api, youtube-api

I'm creating a script that, with the Youtube API, loads the videos in a folder, and then deletes them. Although the video has already been loaded, Python does not allow you to delete the file. It gives me the error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Then I tried to use `os.close(filevar)`, but it returned this error:

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

I tried such a thing to make the variable an integer, but it did not work:

```
newest_file = 1 #Set the value of var in int
os.close(newest_file)   #Close process
newest_file = max(mp4_files, key = os.path.getctime) #Rewrite the var   
os.remove(newest_file)  #Remove the last video
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the file open by your code or by something else? This isn't really a Python problem, it's more of a Windows problem.

Comment: yea, the file is opened in my code

Comment: How do you open the file? The file descriptor (int value you need) should be returned from `os.open`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had this problem, this problem recently appeared when using *os.remove* in windows.
I solved it using the *send2trash* library, instead of deleting the file, the file sends it to the trash.

send2trash.send2trash(newest_file)